# Get generic collection values from DataGridView to Xml file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, generic-list

In my xml file,it has many elements and many child/sub child elements are there so i have decided to load as generic list and display in the DGView and the columns are already created/customed in DGview.

I have to edit the values in the datagridview and serialize back to the file. I would like to know, 
how can i get the values from the datagrid view and serialize back to the file.

I tried using this, `Dataset ds = new Dataset();ds = (Dataset) (dataGridView2.Datasource);ds.WriteXml("XML_File.xml");` i got a error message, nullRefExceptionError.
As I know the DataSet ds is null, thats why I'm getting this error.

I don't want to use the dataset for binding.I want to bind the xml file directly to the datagridview. IS it possible with my approach???

This approach is good but it's not saving the xml file as like  the original xml file:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable("Rules");

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView4.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(dataGridView4.Columns[i].Name, typeof(System.String));
        }

        DataRow myrow;
        int icols = dataGridView4.Columns.Count;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow drow in this.dataGridView4.Rows)
        {
            myrow = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i <= icols - 1; i++)
            {

                myrow[i] = drow.Cells[i].Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(myrow);
        } 

        dt.WriteXml(@"C:\test\items.xml");
```

Any help for me to serilaize/write the values from datagridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adapted this approach for my problem & it works.

```
List<Test>laneConfigs = new List<Test>();//From a class
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                int bbbBorder = 0;
                Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["BBor"].Value.ToString(), out bbbBorder );
                int eeee= 0;
                Int32.TryParse(dr.Cells["EBor"].Value.ToString(), out eee);

                LaneConfig laneConfig = new LaneConfig(
                    dr.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString(),
                    (TrafficLaneType)Enum.Parse(typeof(TrafficLaneType), dr.Cells["Type"].Value.ToString()),
                    new ValueWithUnit<int>(bbbBorder, "mm"),
                    new ValueWithUnit<int>(eee, "mm"));

                laneConfigs.Add(llaneConfig);
            }
```